# Sample dataset(s) for a maximum bipartite matching algorithm test?

Tags: algorithm, dataset, bipartite

I need to test some code I've written to solve the maximum bipartite matching problem. Does anyone know of any examples of large data sets I can use to test? Ideally, these would consist of numerical representations of bipartite graph, preferably of a large size, and even more ideally, containing the solutions ahead of time so that I can check my results.

Comment: If I were you, I'd generate my own datasets. Do you want strictly bipartite graphs, or graphs with bipartite subgraphs?

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to check ur code is to submit it on the online judge system like uva. below is a problem which should be solved by maximum bipartite matching algorithm. you can have a try. all u need to do is to fit the input/output of the problem and then submit it.

[Gopher II](http://acm.uva.es/p/v100/10080.html)